# htaccess parameter to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I would like to redirect this

```
http://www.domain.com/test.php?sub=subdomain&type=cars
```

redirects to

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/cars
```

I already have mod_rewrite rules to do the opposite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%2.com/index.php?route=$1&name=%1 [R=301,L]
```

with htaccess ,help me plz...

Comment: Can you explain your question better and tell what your existing code is doing.

Comment: Thanks [HexaShopping](http://www.hexashopping.com/)

Comment: Thanks [HexaShopping](http://www.hexashopping.com/)

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could test this, tested today, by adding **?** at the end to suppress ${QUERY_STRING} from the returned URL after rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sub=([^&]+)&type=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ http://%1.domain.com/%2? [R=301,L]
```

%{QUERY_STRING} is parsed for the parameters %1 and %2 from RewriteCond.

Test:

```
http://www.domain.com/test.php?sub=subdomain&type=cars
```

Redirected to:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/cars
```

The rewrite rules are tested in the vhosts file or equivalent for apache2 server configuration, and also in .htaccess file, in the latter case one must suppress the root directory slash **/**.

Comment: @user1830181, could you please test my last solution, I would like to known if it works for you ?

Comment: redirection to the new link is working well but it does not execute the page "test.php" and it returns an error,otherwise that the browser does not find the page "test.php"
help me plz...

Comment: As you are redirected to http ://subdomain.domain.com/cars, test.php is not executed as wished. Or you should not redirect it to run test.php. If you do, you should create cars as directory, cgi-executable...

Comment: but cars is second parameter not is directory

Comment: What's you script file under http ://subdomain.domain.com/ directory that shall be executed after Redirect, a kind of target script such as subtest.php, ...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?route=$1&name=%1 [L]

# then the redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?route=([^&]+)&name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.domain.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```